# "No module named x" even though it was just installed with pip

Tags: python, pip

I've created 3 files, `snek.py`, `requirements.txt` and `runsnek.py`. `runsnek.py` installs all the required modules in `requirements.txt` with pip and runs `snek.py`. Everything works fine on Windows 10, but when  trying to run on Ubuntu (WSL2), an error is thrown:

```
❯ python runsnek.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pathlib in /home/rootuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (1.0.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snek.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pathlib import Path
ImportError: No module named pathlib
```

I'm not sure what could've caused the problem on Linux. It might be some kind of pip modules path that isn't defined. `printenv` does not show anything containing the word python.

## files

Here are all of the mentioned files.
`runsnek.py`:

```
import os, platform

os.system('pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt')
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
  os.system('py snek.py')
elif '':
  raise Warning('snek could not be ran, try running snek.py instead')
else:
  os.system('python snek.py')
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
# pip reqs
pathlib
```

`snek.py`:

```
from pathlib import Path
cwd = Path('.')
# [...]
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using python3 instead of python2 inside your WSL2 instance ? Try to check that.

Comment: ❯ python3  
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18)  
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux  
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.  
>>>

Comment: Try `os.system('python3 snek.py')`

Comment: @user56700 damn, it worked. thanks. Do you mind writing an answer so I can select it?

Comment: @JulienSorin You should post an answer as you were the first to see it. :)

Comment: You're running `python`, not `python3`. If you look at `python --version` and `pip --version`, they are probably different. (I ran into this myself just the other day.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using python2 in your WSL2 instance.

In the line `os.system('python snek.py')` it should run python2 instead of python3.

To correct the problem, you can change this line of code by `os.system('python3 snek.py')`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `run` file can be simplified:

```
import sys, os
print('Running with ' + sys.executable)
os.system(sys.executable + ' -m pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt')
os.system(sys.executable +' snek.py')
```

`sys.executable` always contains the path of the python interpreter running the current script. Using `python -m pip install` also ensures that the same python interpreter is used for pip installing, which solves your original problem